# Struts 2.3.8 threads BLOCKED in com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration

Tags: struts2

I'm testing a web application on Tomcat 6 using Struts 2.3.8 version. `devMode` is set to `false`.

I'm finding lot of BLOCKED threads in this method:

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration()
```

This is causing high CPU usage for the application. also find that 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalRelad is taking time which causes getconfiguration (synchronized) to queue up for processing.

Please let me know if anybody has a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with struts 2.3.8. Reported this issue and is resolved in version 2.3.9.

[For more details check this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3971).